# brew install hbase tries to install hadoop though already present

Tags: macos, hadoop, hbase, osx-mavericks, homebrew

Hadoop is already present (and has been working fine for better part of a year)

```
07:48:30/~:177 $which hadoop
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/bin/hadoop
```

But attempting to install hbase results in a hadoop dependency error:

```
07:48:28/~:176 $brew install hbase
==> Installing hbase dependency: hadoop
Warning: Could not link hadoop. Unlinking...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/task-controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I uninstalled hbase this particular error did not recur: instead the following happened:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288842/running-hbase-on-mac-connection-reset-by-peer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
    $ brew upgrade hadoop
    $ brew install hbase
```

Comment: Thanks but I had alrady attempted that. I did retry and no difference.